# JQuery Set the cursor to the end of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on my jquery script to remove the link by replace the text when I click on a button. I have got a problem with the cursor because when I click at the end of the text, it will move the cursor to the start of the text, example: when I click the cursor next to `2!`, it will move the cursor at the start before the `Video`.

When I try this:

```
if (target.prop("nodeName") == "A") {
    unlink(target);
    $('#text_editor').focus().val(selected_text);
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  function unlink(link) {
    var txt = link.text();
    var sp = $("<span>").html(txt);
    link.replaceWith(sp);
  }

  function getObjectFromCursor() {
    var obj, sel = window.getSelection() ? window.getSelection() : document.selection;
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    obj = $(range.startContainer.parentElement);
    return obj;
  }

  $("#toolbar").on("click", "#toolbar_unlink", function() {
    var target = getObjectFromCursor();
    if (target.prop("nodeName") == "A") {
      unlink(target);
      selected_text = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer.wholeText;
      $('#text_editor').focus().val(selected_text);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.toolbar_button_unlink_icon {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/unlink-1507684-1280083.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  opacity: 0.55;
}

.toolbar_button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  width: 28px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: default;
  float: left;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  position: relative;
}

.toolbar_button:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toolbar" class="toolbar_top" role="toolbar" style="height: 100px; user-select: none;">
  <button id="toolbar_unlink" class="toolbar_button toolbar_button_unlink_icon" command="+unlink" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Remove link (‪CTRL+SHIFT+F9)" style="user-select: none; position: relative; margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 13px; outline: none; z-index: 0;" button="" type="button"></button>
</div>
<div id="text_editor" class="editor_message" hidefocus="false" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; height: 500px; width: 100%; padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 18px; font-size: 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1; border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1; border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1; overflow-y: auto;" itacorner="6,7:1,1,0,0">
  <div><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHyIq3boCu0" style="outline: 0px;" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DdHyIq3boCu0&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1577834850425000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHdaxHbwCLaNHaMipTSnrvvbOlhMQ">Video Here 1!</a></div>
  <div><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Video Here 2!</a><br></div>
  <div><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHyIq3boCu0" style="outline: 0px;" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DdHyIq3boCu0&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1577834850425000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHdaxHbwCLaNHaMipTSnrvvbOlhMQ">Video Here 3!</a></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bL71nasw/

What I want to achieve is when I click on the text "Video Here 1!", "Video Here 2!", "Video Here 3!" or whatever it is and when I click on a button to remove the hyperlink to replace with a text, I want to move the cursor next to the text `2!`, `3!` or whatever it is.

Can you please show me example how I can move the cursor next to the text `1!`, `2!`, `3!` or whatever it is in the `contenteditable`?

Thank you.

Comment: Any idea????????????????

Comment: 3 hours and no one have reply???????????